# How to avoid implicit adding of "If-Modified-Since" and "If-None-Match" HTTP headers to NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, http, nsurlconnection, azure-storage, nsurlrequest

I create `NSURLRequest` and don't setup it the "If-Modified-Since" and "If-None-Match" header values, but after debugging and sniffing traffic I see that they are set automatically.

For me it does matter, because I use Windows Azure Storage and it expects the hashed string with all header values in the url.

This issue is present only on Mac OS X (I've tried on 10.7.3). And on iOS it cannot be reproduced.

How to avoid this implicit setting of "If-Modified-Since" and "If-None-Match" headers?

I've tried to change cache policy to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` and it helped, but after some time this issue has appeared again. Very strange behavior.

Comment: @edward To clarify what JustSid said, you don't ask a question at all. On SO, you're expected to ask questions to receive answers, that could hopefully help someone else too later.

Comment: My question is how to avoid such behavior on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I seem to have overcome it by handling the [connection:willCacheResponse:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009947-CH1-BAJIECHD) method of NSURLConnectionDelegate, and returning nil from that method. This prevents the response from being cached which in turn avoids those conditional headers being implicitly added for subsequent requests to the same URL.